# What is "Read an Ebook Week"?

Tags: history

I was just sitting down to start shopping at Smashwords, and found [this listing](https://www.smashwords.com/books/category/1/newest/1).  A quick look on line seems to indicate this is some kind of world wide deal.

- What is "Read an Ebook Week"?
- Where did it get started?
- What is in it for me? (looks like sales maybe?)

Comment: Addressing last bullet; I just spent 8 hours shopping for deals while ignore the never ending snow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's [a pretty lengthy write-up on HuffPo](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/mark-coker/the-story-behind-read-an_b_487343.html).

Short version:

> For one week each year, Rita Toews, 61, a soft-spoken mother of two and grandmother of one, sits at the center of the ebook universe.
>
> Operating from a spare bedroom in her home in Winnipeg, Manitoba, Canada with her cat Lola by her side ("Every author needs a cat," she says), Ms. Toews is the creator and chief ringmaster of Read an Ebook Week, an annual international celebration of ebooks....
>
> For the one week only, publishers and authors offer thousands of original ebooks for free and at deep discounts to encourage book lovers around the globe to give ebooks a try.

It apparently dates to 2004. The domain in the article, [ebookweek.com, now redirects to Valor eBooks](http://ebookweek.com). Not sure of the relation there.